# Android Cotountine Scope not working in Room Callback OnOpen

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm trying to add some data to db but **socpe.launch** not working in this code
from [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#12) i'm learn

```
@Database(entities = [Type::class, LogKeuangan::class], version = 7)
abstract class TypeRoomDb : RoomDatabase(){
    var TAG = "TypeRoomDb"
    abstract fun typeDao() : TypeDao
    abstract fun logKeuanganDao() : LogKeuanganDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE : TypeRoomDb? = null

        fun getDataBase(
            context: Context,
            scope: CoroutineScope
        ): TypeRoomDb {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    TypeRoomDb::class.java,
                    Cons.DB_NAME
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(
                        TypeDbCallBack(
                            scope
                        )
                    )
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance

                instance
            }
        }

        private class TypeDbCallBack(
            private val scope: CoroutineScope
        ) : RoomDatabase.Callback(){
            override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpen(db)
                LogTest().e(TAG = "TypeDbCallBack", data = "on create ")
                INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        LogTest().e("TypeDbCallBack", "on create scope.launch")
                        populateDb(
                            database.typeDao()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun populateDb(typeDao: TypeDao){
            typeDao.deleteAll()
            LogTest().e("TypeRoomDb", "populateDb")
            /*out*/
            typeDao.insert(
                Type(
                    "000",
                    "FOOD",
                    0,
                    "FFFFFF",
                    ""
                )
            )
           

            /*in*/
            typeDao.insert(
                Type(
                    "500",
                    "SALARY",
                    1,
                    "FFFFFF",
                    ""
                )
            )
            
            
        }

    }
}
```

this log is working LogTest().e(TAG = "TypeDbCallBack", data = "on create ")
but my log inside **scope.launh** not working

i'm trying to make database use room library

I think this error appears after changing the package name

Comment: Which scope is it? From where are you providing that?

Comment: i'm make database use room library,
in Callback i want to call populateDb() but in scope.launch not running
i have 1 log inside onOpen, and 1 log inside scope.launch 
log inside scope.launch not running

Comment: What's the origin of the scope? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), unless we know information about the scope we can't do anything about your problem, you have to specify from where you are calling `getDataBase()` and how you are providing the scope.

Comment: sorry, i'm update my code